# Calculating the area of the total buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, buffer, area

I'm struggling to find out how one should calculate the total area of the buffer in QGIS. I'm doing a home range analysis by using buffer. But I need to find out the total area as well.

Answer (score 4):

`sum($area)` gives you the sum of the area of all polygons in your layer using the unit of measurement your CRS is based on - so usually sqm, unless you used EPSG:4326. You may either add this as an attribute to all polygons, or you may just write the number down.